# Control and capture free falling grains

Tags: machine-design, flow-control

I'm a rookie engineer with experience in Fusion 360 and eagle. I am trying to solve a huge problem I'm facing with respect to capturing 360 degree images of wheat grains that are free-falling. I have 3 cameras with independent illumination systems and focussing lens that are placed below a funnel that has a small output and that lets the grains out. I have 2 problems with the current system:

1. I have tried global shutter cameras and a proximity sensor for triggering the shutter, but it is still too slow.
2. The grains of different sizes jam the funnel many a time and rate of flow is not controlled.

Objective: I am trying to build a scanner that can analyse the physical defects in the grain to provide good pricing for farmers that bring in better (insect damage free) produce. To make it affordable, there should not be a lot of moving parts...

Comment: feed with an auger might control the flow rate and minimise jamming.

Comment: I'll just comment that's pretty impressive if they aim to capture images of every single grain. I'm sure it adds up to enormous data storage requirements

Comment: Old fashioned method: take several samples as you pour.  Photograph the samples in your desired environment under controlled conditions. These conditions may even be at the top of the silo if you can start/stop the flow.
 Photography trick: move the camera as you take the shot.  This can be a rotation movement on the camera's part, in which case the velocity must match angular rate times distance from camera. You can put the camera inside a dome so that rotation is contained and no externally mobile parts are there to snag.

Comment: @RC_23 We are not storing the images but building a tensorflow model that analyses the pictures and derives information, post which this data is saved. Saving three pictures for each grain will be nuts 